# Is there a streamlined way to invoke java functions from rust?

Tags: java, rust, java-native-interface, rust-macros

My understanding of invoking java from rust via the `jni` crate involves a bit of boilerplate that looks like

```
je.call_method(self.rimuru, "shell2Pixels", "(II[B)V", &[
    JValue::from(width),
    JValue::from(height),
    JValue::from(rgbs.as_obj()),
])?;
```

I am imagining that this could be improved using macros.  Perhaps something like

`java_call_method!(self.rimuru, "shell2Pixels", (), width, height, rgbs)?;`

The macro would be responsible for building the signature string `(II[B)V` from the types of the various arguments.

Does something like this already exist and I have not discovered it?  I am not sure if it can be implemented using regular macros instead of procedural macros.

Comment: Does the string `(II[B)V` indicate the types of the arguments you're passing, or the types the function is expecting? In the later case, a macro that would build that string would be very unsafe.

Comment: the (II[B)V indicates the types passed to the macro.  If they do not match what is available in the java class, then I expect java to throw a `NoSuchMethodException`.

Comment: This approach might work for primitive types but quickly becomes unworkable for reference types (objects and arrays).  What you *could* do is interpret the given type signature at compile time and use it to type check the arguments.

Comment: support for objects and arrays would be kind of tricky, and I imagine multiple layers of support would be possible (one where you just have to pass a `jobject`, and other fancier layers where you have templatized wrapper classes).  I will not be tackling that in version 1.

Answer (score 1):

After a great deal of wallowing in confusion I have created https://github.com/mutantbob/rust_jni_boilerplate which has a small set of procedural macros that generate boilerplate.

(as of 2020-Aug) It is used like this:

```
struct Widget<'a> {
    jni_env: &'a AttachGuard<'a>,
    java_this: AutoLocal<'a,'a>,
}

impl<'a> JavaConstructible<'a> for Widget<'a>
{
    fn wrap_jobject(jni_env:&'a AttachGuard<'a>, java_this: AutoLocal<'a,'a>) -> Widget<'a>
    {
        Widget {
            jni_env,
            java_this,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Widget<'a> {

    // define a rust function named new
    jni_constructor! { com.purplefrog.rust_callables.Widget () }
    jni_constructor! { new_one=com.purplefrog.rust_callables.Widget (&str) }

    jni_instance_method! { count () -> i32 }
    jni_instance_method! { sumLen () -> i32 }

    jni_instance_method! { add(&str) }

    jni_instance_method! { echo_str=echo(&str)->String }
    jni_instance_method! { echo_char=echo(char)->char }
    jni_instance_method! { echo_byte=echo(i8)->i8 }
    jni_instance_method! { echo_short=echo(i16)->i16 }
    jni_instance_method! { echo_int=echo(i32)->i32 }
    jni_instance_method! { echo_long=echo(i64)->i64 }

    jni_instance_method! { to_strings = toStrings() ->Vec<String> }
}
```

There are probably gaping holes in its type support.  Its architecture has mutated drastically during development.  I'm not even sure I'm using the procedural macro API idiomatically.  The `jni` crate it is based on can hardly be considered safe (it is *very* easy to leak memory when you are calling java from rust).  But I have managed to make it work for my limited use case.

I am hoping it serves as an inspiration for someone else to do better.  Maybe it will be useful as an example of how to write procedural macros until someone writes a proper article (google search didn't exactly give me any good articles about it).